# Unlink a file from FUSE virtual file system

Tags: fuse, unlink, virtualfilesystem

I am new to FUSE. I created a virtual file system via FUSE. I can read a file with the command:

```
cat /deneme/club/basketball/students/student1
```

and it returns the value of file correctly:

```
"111111111"
```

However, I want to delete same file from file system. I use unlink system call:

```
unlink /deneme/club/basketball/students/student1
```

This code does not give any error but when I called the cat for the same file, it prints the same value:

```
"111111111"
```

What should i do to remove file from file system. Thanks

[This is how i declared the unlink operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjGr.png)

Comment: Did you implement fuse lib unlink? How?

Comment: @OrenKishon There is no implementation. I actually thought there might be a default even if I didnt do anything. After that, I added a simple code and editted my question you can see it on image.

Comment: Returning 0 ("success") makes the kernel believe you have done the remove work on your side. That's why the shell shows no error. If you wouldn't have declared unlink, at least it would have output an error. https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/e6df67cf1f6e895c9f72bb3756cfc186d4e78390/lib/fuse.c#L1661

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the system call unlink and passing the file path as a parameter to the system call.

```
unlink(file_path);
```